# How to deserialize file into DTO play framework java

Tags: java, playframework, jackson

I have a POST request whose body contains this json:

```
{
   "fileType": "excel",
   "fileBody": "dasdasomdaojawd"
}
```

I have a dto like this in my project:

```
Public class import{
  String fileType;
  String fileBody;
}
```

What type should I specify for '**fileBody**', given that it is file bytes, so that play framework will correctly deserialize this stream of bytes into my dto.

In spring-boot I would label it MultipartFile, but play framework doesn't have that option.

The standard way of pulling a file from a request is as follows:

```
Http.MultipartFormData body = req.body().asMultipartFormData();
Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart fileItem = body.getFile("fileBody");
```

But can I deserialize the file directly into dto at least in some form?
Maybe I can stick it in String form first and then convert it to Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart?
Please give me a hint.

Comment: Your question is confusing: what exactly is the data you are receiving as input in terms of HTTP request? Is it a JSON body with strings content? Or is it a file through multipart data?

Comment: It's http post request which contains multipart data + fileType

Comment: Then I think you have to read the multipart separately and for one part use the JSON parsing, for the other the file "parsing". I don't think you can represent multipart in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the JsonNode from the request

```
Http.Request req = request();

// get the body  
Http.RequestBody reqBody = req.body()

// Convert it into JsonNode

JsonNode node = reqBody.asJson();

// simply parse it using Json.fromJson(jsonNode,class)
import imp = Json.fromJson(node,import.class)
```

It uses ObjectMapper object which reads values from the node and parse it by matching it with class provided.
For more information refer to : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model